# Would satellites going into a rendez-vous show a difference in potential leading to an arc between the structures?

Tags: artificial-satellite, spacecraft, low-earth-orbit

I'm researching into satellite rendez-vous. I know (NASA-HDBK-4006A) that in space (more precisely LEO) there is a plasma made up with electrons and atomic ions and a 'plasma potential'. I also learnt that because of the different potentials in a satellite, mainly for the solar arrays, arcs can happen between satellite points due to the conductive nature of plasma.

For my case of a satellite approaching another one, the whole maneuver will take a number of orbits, so several hours and my first thought is that if two satellites are for that long in the same plasma region they would have similar voltages so the danger of arcs or strong charge interchanges is reduced. Am I right in thinking that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [EMI from Spacecraft Docking Systems Spacecraft Charging - Plasma Contact Potentials](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20140010649),

> It has been
> thought that, before the two objects come into close proximity
> and dock, the two metallic objects in the conducting plasma
> media of the ionosphere would, over the course of time in
> orbit, come to similar potentials and there would be no
> significant potential differences between the CEV and the
> docking spacecraft. The conducting plasma media in the
> ionosphere would essentially connect the CEV and docking
> spacecraft electrically at-a-distance before mechanical contact
> occurs and would allow the CEV and docking spacecraft
> potentials to come to a common potential before docking,
> neutralizing any potential differences, thereby, preventing any
> severe ESD event from occurring. However, as is shown in
> this paper, the separate Debye sheaths that develop around the
> CEV and the docking spacecraft in the plasma ionosphere
> isolate the two conducting objects in the plasma media, and
> this equilibration does not occur until the moment of docking.

(Where CEV means "[Crewed Exploration Vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_Exploration_Vehicle)", and the example docking spacecraft or VV, "visiting vehicle" in the paper was the [Orion Service Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Service_Module), but those are fairly unimportant details)

This suggests to me, at least, that time in orbit probably *isn't* going to save you here. It isn't entirely compelling though.

But going back to the title of your question, "*Would satellites going into a rendez-vous show a difference in potential leading to an arc between the structures?*", the conclusion of the paper states:

> when the CEV is biased to a high negative
> potential, with sunlit solar arrays, there is a larger potential
> difference between the CEV and the VV. Therefore, when
> docking in the light, there is the possibility of creating an ESD
> arc (or a coronal discharge).
> No neutralization can occur until the CEV and the VV are
> within the Debye distance of each other, which is only
> approximately 7 mm for the worst- case CEV LEO conditions.

So arcing *may* be possible under worst-case conditions, but

> The contact potential between the International Space Station
> (ISS) and the Space Shuttle (SS) has been monitored with
> Langmuir Probes mounted on the ISS on every docking
> mission. The contact potential has been no greater than ≈ -80
> V (approximately half of the solar array bias) on any docking
> operation and no serious Electromagnetic Interference (EMI)
> effects have been noted on any of the ISS and/or SS
> equipment after docking

it doesn't appear to be a particularly big deal, given whatever anti-ESD measures are already in use.

Comment: 5000V is a "typical" doorknob static shock so 80V should be negligible?